# You can't use both --strict and --wip (RuntimeError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.1, cucumber

I'm using cucumber for BDD and I used @wip tag for a certain scenario that I want to focus on. But when I try to run "cucumber --wip" it gives an error that says " You can't use both --strict and --wip (RuntimeError)" Any suggestions on how to debug it?

PS: I am using cucumber 1.1.4, cucumber-rails "1.2.1", rails "3.1.0"

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's possible that Cucumber is getting the `--strict` option from a profile.  Do you have a `cucumber.yml` file in your project directory or `config` subdirectory?  If so, you can add a line to it like this:

```
wip: --wip
```

Then, you can use the work-in-progress feature without `--strict` being silently appended, like so:

```
cucumber --profile=wip
```

The Cucumber wiki has a page with more info on [Cucumber profiles](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/cucumber.yml).

Comment: Yes, and it works! I also used rake cucumber:wip and it also works great.